# How do I get 1366x768 resolution working on 12.04 with nvidia GTX275

Tags: nvidia, display, resolution, tv

My PC (VGA Nvidia GTX275) is connected directly to a TV (Philips 42" lcd) and Ubuntu does not recognize the native resolution, the closest working resolution is 1280x768
I have tried some xorg tricks found on Google but have had no luck

Any idea how to set the native resolution?

Comment: I think the user has model [42PF5421](http://www.p4c.philips.com/cgi-bin/cpindex.pl?ctn=42PF5421/10&scy=US&slg=ENG) (check out the leaflet for more info) -- [xrandr output](http://forum.ubuntu-gr.org/viewtopic.php?p=242577#p242577) -- the resolution 1366x768 is not supported according to the manual, but the user mentioned that it works in Windows XP (if it's the same user as the one from ubuntu-gr). Looks like a linux nvidia driver issue.

Answer (score 1):

I was faced with a similar dilemma when I hooked up my pc to a Philips 42" LCD (model 42PFL5704D/F7). You can have it set up at at that resolution (i have mine at 1920 x 1080 - and it's great.
To do that you need to install the proprietary drivers from Nvidia. Simply open the terminal and enter the following commands, one line at a time:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
```

The reason being that the latest drivers has not yet made it to Ubuntu's repositories.

Note 1: I think the resolution you were going for is 1360x768.
Note 2: Make sure your tv is setup to unscaled (Menu > TV Settings > Picture > Unscaled).