# upgraded to 12.04 now no audio over AMD HDMI

Tags: sound, hdmi, ati

I've looked this issue up a bunch, but most of the solutions are unity solutions. i am using XFCE and Can't seem to find the new ubuntu settings control panel.

I am using mythbuntu, and I upgraded from 11.10 to 12.04. Now I am not getting audio over HDMI. I'm sure it's a simple problem, but all the solutions I've looked up have not resolved it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a kernel problem

Do this an the sound will come back

[No sound on HDMI with Radeon driver](https://askubuntu.com/questions/67113/fast-video-playback-with-no-sound)

Comment: This resolved my situation. After I added this to my grub launch flags all I had to do was configure mythtv to use HDMI out (which previously did not produce sound).

Answer (score -1):

Are you using an nvidia video card for your HDMI output? If so, refer to this solution, it might just be a driver issue.

[How do I get 1366x768 resolution working on 12.04 with nvidia GTX275](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126894/how-do-i-get-1366x768-resolution-working-on-12-04-with-nvidia-gtx275/137567#137567)

Let me know if this solves your problem.

Comment: It says in the title, right beside HDMI, "AMD".